# Module not found: Can't resolve '@contentful/rich-text-react-renderer'

Tags: typescript, next.js, contentful, richtext, contentful-api

I am working on a Next.js project with Typescript. I fetch content from Contentful CMS. After fetching content I want to convert `rich-text` it to HTML code. for that purpose, I follow the instruction of contentful. link- https://www.contentful.com/developers/docs/javascript/tutorials/rendering-contentful-rich-text-with-javascript/

In order to install the `contentful/rich-text-react-renderer'` package with `npm`. I face an error when importing the package in my component.

```
Module not found: Can't resolve '@contentful/rich-text-react-renderer'
  2 | import Hero from "@/component/Hero";
  3 | import { client } from "@/component/client";
> 4 | import {documentToReactComponents} from '@contentful/rich-text-react-renderer';
  5 |
```

That should give me the string like this-

```
<p class="align-center"><span class="bold">Hello</span><u> world!</u></p>
```

Comment: Hey Osama, can you provide more details to reproduce this? I created a Next.js TypeScript project and everything seems to work for me.